# JavaScript Not validating my form

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["Email"].value;
var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>x.length || x="" || x=str.search(" ");) 
{
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address!!");
        return false;

}
var y = document.forms["Password"].value;
if(y.length>6)
else
{
        alert("Minimum 6 Characters Required!!");
        return false;

}
var vl = document.forms["Phno"].value;
for (var i = 0; i<vl.length; i++)
{
    if((vl[i]!="a" && vl[i]!="b" && vl[i]!="c" && vl[i]!="d" && vl[i]!="e"               &&    vl[i]!="f" && vl[i]!="g" && vl[i]!="h" 

&& vl[i]!="i" && vl[i]!="j" && vl[i]!="k" && vl[i]!="l" && vl[i]!="m" && vl[i]!="n" &&     vl[i]!="o" && vl[i]!="p" && vl[i]!="q" && 

 vl[i]!="r" && vl[i]!="s" && vl[i]!="t" && vl[i]!="u" && vl[i]!="v" && vl[i]!="w" &&                         vl[i]!="x" && vl[i]!="y" &&  vl[i]!="z" && vl

   [i]!="@" && vl[i]!="_" && vl[i]!="." && vl[i]!="-"))
    {

        alert("Enter a valid Phone Number!!");
        return false;
    }
}
if(vl.lenght>10 || vl.lenght<10)
{
    alert("Enter a valid Phone Number!! ");
    return false;
}   

var d = document.forms["date"].value;
if(d="")
return false;
else
return true;
}
```

```
    <form method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()">
          <center> <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom:                                                                        10px;"  id="Email" name="Email" 

type="email" placeholder="Email"> 
           <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom: 10px;" id="Password" name="Password" 

type="Password" placeholder="Password">
           <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom: 10px;" id="Phno" name="Phno" 

type="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone No">
           <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom: 10px;" id="date" name="date" type="date" 

placeholder="DOB">
                   <button type="submit" style="border: 1px solid; background-color:#3079ed; width:274px;height:44px;" 

class="button"><b>Sign Up</b></button>      
</center>
</form>
```

I am new to java script and currently learning it.
My browser  is only validating the Email field and skipping the rest of the field
why is this as my brackets are proper. And i have mentioned return true only after the last field.

Comment: It's because you are returning false inside the email condition

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>x.length || x="" || x=str.search(" ");) 
{
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address!!");
        return false; // I'm talking about this

}

Comment: You should look at using a regular expression for validating strings, e.g. `/^[a-z@_\.]+$/i.test(vl)` might replace all those `||` expressions.

Comment: you have too many errors there i'll corrected and post it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(UPDATE)**

***The Form (notice the "return validateForm();" instead of "validateForm()":***

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
          <center> <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom:                                                                        10px;"  id="Email" name="Email" 

type="email" placeholder="Email"> 
           <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom: 10px;" id="Password" name="Password" 

type="Password" placeholder="Password">
           <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom: 10px;" id="Phno" name="Phno" 

type="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone No">
           <input style="padding: 5 10px;width:274px;height:44px;margin-bottom: 10px;" id="date" name="date" type="date" 

placeholder="DOB">
                   <button type="submit" style="border: 1px solid; background-color:#3079ed; width:274px;height:44px;" 

class="button"><b>Sign Up</b></button>      
</center>
</form>
```

***The Function  note the GetElementById() instead of forms[] : ***

```
 function validateForm() {
var x = document.getElementById("Email").value;
var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>x.length || x==="" ||x.indexOf(" ")>=0)
{
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address!!");
        return false;

}
var y = document.getElementById("Password").value;
if(y.length<6)
{
        alert("Minimum 6 Characters Required!!");
        return false;

}
var vl = document.getElementById("Phno").value;
for (var i = 0; i<vl.length; i++)
{
    if(isNaN(vl[i]))
    {
        alert("Enter a valid Phone Number!!");
        return false;
    }
}
if(vl.lenght!=10)
{
    alert("Enter a valid Phone Number!! ");
    return false;
}   

var d = document.getElementById("date").value;
if(d==="")
return false;

return true;
}
```

Comment: No still skipping the rest of the fields

Comment: Nope still not validating

Comment: can you post the form ?

Comment: you should use getElementbyId il will update right now its working i just test it :D